# Where is the best place to find stock website templates?

Tags: template

I think I'm in the majority of programmers in saying I can't do visual design for s***. But I do write programs occasionally, and I'd like to have a nice website to tell people about said programs. I used to use a site called "OSWD" to find templates, but it's been forever since it's been looked at, and most of the designs seem overly specifically tailored to a single kind of site -- for example, a site featuring a large picture of an ice cube wouldn't make much sense for a site displaying software for people to use.

I know there are plenty of template sites out there which have freely available designs, but I'm not sure which ones are good, and which ones are garbage.

Where is the best place to find website templates?

Comment: Are you looking for layout templates or just color/style templates?

Comment: @BenV: Sorry, I'm not sure what the difference is :(

Comment: Made CW; see here for reason why it wasn't available:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183

Answer (score 3):

Try [openwebdesign.org](http://openwebdesign.org) or [freecsstemplates.org](http://freecsstemplates.org)

Also, [www.sxc.hu](http://www.sxc.hu) for "free" photos.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [themeforest](http://themeforest.net) they have site templates, psd, wordpress tempplates or individual icons/buttons etc you should be able to put together or buy someing pretty clean and sharp from there without too much graphic deisgn skills, basically if you find something you really like you can just get the psd and slice it to html yourself or if your feeling lazy and want a quick (only quick not necessarily good) result buy a full template and amend as necessary.

caveat from re-reading your question you asked for free, these are not free but $20 is nto a terrible amount of money for a site that looks good imo

Answer (score 1):

There are some great skins for the dominant CMS-es out there, such as WordPress, Drupal and Joomla. It's sometimes useful to snip parts of their CSS, too.

I wouldn't go so far to suggest this route is better than any of the other ideas or sites that are being suggested here, but I think you might get some good ideas from them.