# HTML + CSS Template

Tags: html, css, template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the best place to find stock website templates?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/where-is-the-best-place-to-find-stock-website-templates)

I need some html + css templates (not for wordpress or any kind of cms) used for custom website.
It's not important if they are free, opensource or premium templates to buy.
I'd like to hear your opinion about the website you suggest to me.

I actually use these website:

- templatebox.com
- os-templates.com
- freecsstemplates.org

These are good website, but sometimes I can't find what I need because they are too "standard" and not creative!

Thanks to everyone for help me!

Comment: @paulmorriss sorry about that... I tried to find what I need, but I didn't find that questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few out there, my personal favorite is themeforest.com they have very high quality templates for just about everything from facebook, plain html, to wordpress.

Comment: Thanks a lot! themeforest.com has beautiful template! They're also cheap then others!